# VBA how to add object to array by value

Tags: excel, vba, visio

I have a Visual Basic for Applications (Excel) script I am trying to make, and part of that script involves filling an array with shape objects

Snippet as follows:

```
If rw3("PROCEDURE_ID_TRUE") = currPage Or rw3("PROCEDURE_ID_TRUE") = currPage Then
                Dim ShapeObj2 As Visio.Shape
                Set ShapeObj2 = AppVisio.Documents.Item("BASFLO_U.vssx").Masters.ItemU("Process").Shapes(1)
                ShapeObj2.Name = Str(rw3("REGISTRATION_CONTROL_ID")) & "_Link"
                ShapeObj2.NameU = Str(rw3("REGISTRATION_CONTROL_ID")) & "_Link"
                ShapeObj2.Text = Str(rw3("REGISTRATION_CONTROL_ID")) & "_Link"
               
                Set prevPageLinks(i) = ShapeObj2
                i = i + 1
End If
```

Whenever I actually run this, it seems to be passing ShapeObj2 by reference. The entire array will always end up being whatever the last value of ShapeObj2 is.

How do I change this behavior? The Visio library does not allow for “New Visio.Shape”

Comment: You haven't really provided enough code for us to workout what is happening.  At the moment you add .Shapes(1) in the if statement, Should this be .item(i)>

Comment: I'm not a Visio person, but you have to actually add a new shape. I'm not sure if that's with [`Drop`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/visio.shape.drop) or some other relevant method (maybe [`Copy`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/visio.shape.drop))

Comment: Since you all the time, for each iteration, set **the same shape** `Set ShapeObj2 = AppVisio.Documents.Item("BASFLO_U.vssx").Masters.ItemU("Process").Shapes(1)`, what (else) do you expect from the above (insufficient) code fragment?

Comment: From the [`Set`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/set-statement) documentation: "Generally, when you use Set to assign an object reference to a variable, no copy of the object is created for that variable. Instead, a reference to the object is created." You have multiple references to the same underlying object. To have multiple objects, you must create them.

Comment: I am completely unsure what I should be adding to the snippet for context. The entire failure is right there. I am creating a shape, editing some attributes, and adding it to the array. The array declaration is ```Dim prevPageLinks(30) As Visio.Shape``` if that somehow helps. My problem is that it’s all being done by reference it seems, and I want it pass the object to the array by value (save a copy to the array, not a reference)

Comment: @Tony You are actually grabbing a shape, editing some attributes, and adding the shape to the array.  And every time through the loop, you grab the same shape.  That's what freeflow and FaneDuru are getting at.

Comment: @Tony Also, if you can't New a Shape object, see if there is a Copy method available as suggested by BigBen.

Comment: Yes. I understand how it works. It is passing by reference. What I am asking is if there is a way to explicitly _not_ do that.

Comment: You have to create a new object for each iteration, as I already mentioned.

Comment: Figured it out, going to add it as an answer

Comment: I am afraid it is not  a matter of PASSING BY Reference. Your understanding regarding what `Set` does is wrong. It does  not create a new object! You set the same object and only modify its properties. You should check if VBA Corel uses `duplicate` (like CorelDRAW) or simple Copy the initial shape to obtain a new one. Only after that you may place DIFFERENT objects in the array.

Comment: The code example here and many of the comments are just guesses. Please look at the Visio SDK for how to access shapes in stencils and instantiate them.

Answer (score 2):

As it turns out, Visio has a .duplicate on their shape object which returns an exact copy of the object built in, and I just overlooked it.

The syntax I used was to just change
`Set ShapeObj2 = AppVisio.Documents.Item("BASFLO_U.vssx").Masters.ItemU("Process").Shapes(1)`

To
`Set ShapeObj2 = AppVisio.Documents.Item("BASFLO_U.vssx").Masters.ItemU("Process").Shapes(1).Duplicate`

This will obviously not work for everything, as VBA requires you to make a new object every time as it does not copy by value by default, but this is a functional solution for my needs.

Comment: It will work for every shape! I do not work in Visio, but I suggested it by assimilation with CorelDRAW VBA. I do not know if Visio uses layers, but in Corel you can place such a shape on another layer, too.

Comment: `Duplicate` also adds it to the page (according to the docs).  This isn't an issue for what you are doing?

Comment: Interestingly duplicate does *not* add it to the page until I specifically drop it. If I do that set like that, it’s effectively like .copy for other objects. Visio has a .copy that copies things to the clipboard and a .paste, but those automatically drop with no reference to the created shape. I found a post referencing this and someone said “use .duplicate instead” and facepalmed.

Comment: You need to use the .Drop method, at least, intially. The .Duplicate method can be used thereafter, but .Drop will always work. I suggest you download and look at the Visio SDK, there are many examples of how to code for Visio in VBA.